# Custom actionbar home button not responding

Tags: android

In my app, I am using a custom action bar. Then I tried to add a Home Button to open the Navigation Drawer. But when I tried to click the button, nothing happened. The Home Button isn't responding to clicks.

Here's my code:
**activity_main.xml:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="android.example.com.errorhomeasupbutton.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/main_nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/main_nav_view_header"
            app:menu="@menu/main_nav_view_menu"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_drawer_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: where you create custom toolbar?

Comment: The `<DrawerLayout>` is covering the `Toolbar`, and intercepting touch events. Get rid of the `<LinearLayout>`, as it's rather pointless, and add `android:layout_below="@id/main_toolbar"` to the opening `<DrawerLayout>` tag.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @MikeM.. It worked..